# Program crash when using calloc (works fine when in debug)

Tags: c, calloc

My program works fine in debug mode but when I try it in release, it always crash when arriving when I use a `calloc`. The weird thing is that I use exactly the same way to write my `calloc` several times in a row and the crash only occurs the third time...

This is a bit of my code for you to get what I mean :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Normes.h"
#define   EPS 1.0e-14


void atimes(int n, float x[], float r[], int itrnsp, int *ija, float *sa);
void dsprsax(float *sa, int *ija, float *x, float *b, int n);
void dsprstx(float* sa, int *ija, float *x, float *b, int n);
float produit_scalaire(float *x, float *y, int n);
void asolve(int n, float b[], float x[], int itrnsp, int *ija, float *sa);




int linbcg(int n, float b[], float x[], int itol, float tol, int itmax, int *iter, float *err, int *ija, float *sa)
{

    *iter = 0;
    int flag;
    float bnrm2;
    float omega;
    float rho;
    float beta;
    float rho_1;
    float alpha;
    float resid;
    int i;

    float *r=NULL;
    float *vecteur_temporaire=NULL;
    float *r_tilde=NULL;
    float *p=NULL;
    float *p_hat=NULL;
    float *v=NULL;
    float *s=NULL;
    float *s_hat=NULL;
    float *t=NULL;



vecteur_temporaire=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (vecteur_temporaire==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

printf("\nok1\n");

r=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (r==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

printf("\nok2\n");

r_tilde=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (r_tilde==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

printf("\nok3\n");

p=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (p==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

p_hat=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (p_hat==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

v=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (v==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

s=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (s==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

s_hat=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (s_hat==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

t=calloc((n+1), sizeof(float));
        if (t==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

    bnrm2 = norme2(b, n);
    if (bnrm2==0)
    {
        bnrm2=1;
    }


    atimes(n, x, vecteur_temporaire, 0, ija, sa);
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        r[i] = b[i] - vecteur_temporaire[i];
    }

    *err = norme2(r, n)/bnrm2;
    if (*err < tol) return 0;

    omega = 1.0;

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        r_tilde[i] = r[i];
    }


    while (*iter<=itmax)
    {
        (*iter)++;
         rho = produit_scalaire(r, r_tilde, n);

        if (rho==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (*iter>1)
        {
            beta = (rho/rho_1)*(alpha/omega);


            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                p[i] = r[i]+beta*(p[i] - omega*v[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                p[i] = r[i];
            }
        }
//printf("\nrho=%.2f   iter=%d   p[1]=%.2f", rho, *iter, p[1]);


        asolve(n, p, p_hat, 0, ija, sa);

        atimes(n, p_hat, v, 0, ija, sa);

        alpha = rho/(produit_scalaire(r_tilde, v, n));

        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                s[i] = r[i] - alpha*v[i];
            }

        if (norme2(s, n)<tol)
        {
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                x[i] = x[i] + alpha*p_hat[i];
            }
        resid = norme2(s, n)/bnrm2;
        }

        asolve(n, s, s_hat, 0, ija, sa);

        atimes(n, s_hat, t, 0, ija, sa);
//printf("\nnorme(s) = %.2f , norme(s_hat) = %.2f\n\n", norme2(s, n), norme2(s_hat, n));


//printf("\nt = (%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f)   omega = %.2f", t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], omega);
        omega = produit_scalaire(t, s, n)/produit_scalaire(t, t, n);
//printf("\t... %.2f", omega);
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                x[i] = x[i] + alpha*p_hat[i]+omega*s_hat[i];
                r[i] = s[i] - omega*t[i];
            }

        *err = norme2(r, n)/bnrm2;
//printf("\niter = %d  ,  err = %.2f , numerr = %.2f , omega = %.2f, t = (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f)", *iter, *err, norme2(r, n), omega, t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4]);

        if (*err<=tol)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (omega == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        rho_1=rho;
    }


    if (*err<=tol)                  //manque une condition mais on essaie comme ça
    {
        flag =0;
    }
    else if (omega == 0.0)
    {
        flag = -2;
    }
    else if (rho == 0.0)
    {
        flag = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        flag =1;
    }



free(r);
free(r_tilde);
free(p);
free(p_hat);
free(v);
free(s);
free(s_hat);
free(t);
free(vecteur_temporaire);


    return flag;
}
/*flag indique la réussite de l'algorithme :
flag = 0 : solution trouvee au taux d'errer impose
flag = 1 : pas de convergence apres le nombre maximum de convergences autorisees
flag = -1 : breakdown : rho = 0
flag = -2 : breakdown : omega = 0
*/







void atimes(int n, float x[], float r[], int itrnsp, int *ija, float *sa)
{

    void dsprsax(float sa[], int ija[], float x[], float b[], int n);

    void dsprstx(float sa[], int ija[], float x[], float b[], int n);
            //These are float versions of sprsax and sprstx. if (itrnsp) dsprstx(sa,ija,x,r,n);

    if (itrnsp) dsprstx(sa, ija, x, r, n);
    else dsprsax(sa, ija, x, r, n);
}



void dsprsax(float *sa, int *ija, float *x, float *b, int n)
{
    void nrerror();
    int i,k;

    if (ija[1] != n+2) printf("dsprsax: mismatched vector and matrix");
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        b[i]=sa[i]*x[i];
        for (k=ija[i];k<=ija[i+1]-1;k++) b[i] += sa[k]*x[ija[k]];
    }
}


void dsprstx(float* sa, int *ija, float *x, float *b, int n)
{
    void nrerror();
    int i,j,k;
    if (ija[1] != n+2) printf("mismatched vector and matrix in dsprstx");

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) b[i]=sa[i]*x[i];

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {

        for (k=ija[i];k<=ija[i+1]-1;k++) {
            j=ija[k];
            b[j] += sa[k]*x[i];
            }
    }
}

float produit_scalaire(float *x, float *y, int n)
{
    float ans = 0;
    int i;

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        ans = ans + x[i]*y[i];
    }

return ans;
}


void asolve(int n, float b[], float x[], int itrnsp, int *ija, float *sa)
    {
        int i;

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) x[i]=b[i];  /*(sa[i]!=0 ? b[i]/sa[i] : b[i]);*/
        //The matrix A is the diagonal part of A, stored in the first n elements of sa. Since the transpose matrix has the same diagonal, the flag itrnsp is not used.
        return;
    }
```

So here I initialize several pointers then try to allocate them, it works fine for the first two (`vecteur_temporaire` and `r`) but fail when trying to allocate the third, `r_tilde` (ie. on my console, ok1 and ok2 are printed but the program crash before printing ok3).

I don't think I lack memory (here `n = 21` so that's not so bad, and I tested printing something if `r==NULL` but nothing is printed).

Do you know what can be the cause of such a problem? I'm not really surprised it works in debug mode (apparently it's usual), but I can't get why it works twice but not the third time. Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is the value of `n` in the call to `calloc`?

Comment: you must have a memory corruption somewhere else. Ensure in the rest of the code that you don't write outside your variable's space.

Comment: Are you running just the code shown? There may be a memory corruption that happens earlier that affects your third `calloc`. Could you try Valgrind?

Comment: I think it would be useful to show us a compilable program with `main()`, etc

Comment: `core` file should help you to analyse the problem

Comment: @koan hmm I think the whole program is a bit too long to fit in here... (that is just a function here) and it is quite a mess...

Comment: I think it does not seem like there is a particular problem in this part of the code, already memory corruption is occurring in other parts.

Comment: @Arkadiy the value of n here is 21. I've tried it with a bigger value (something like 120 000) and it works fine ... weird.
And the code is much longer in real but it's just the beginning of a function, and I never used r_tilde anywhere else... Plus I'm on windows, Valgrind is only for linux no ? I guess there are equivalent memory debugger for Windows though.

Comment: @olivm is it possible that something I do later in the code could affect what happens here ? or are you only talking about what happens before?

Comment: @qrdl I'll try that (although I don't know anything about core files... well, I will learn !)

Comment: @PierreGilfriche can only be before (timely speaking). Some pointer work going wrong, some array written in a too small space, etc. You MUST track this down if you want your whole work to be stable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean? I could have corrupted memory without noticing earlier and the error just appears there ? even if I have never used 'r_tilde' earlier?

Comment: @olivm okay but given that the error is only visible here how can I have an idea of where it comes from ? with the core files maybe ? (i don't know i just heard about them so I can try ...)

Comment: Post where you use your 2nd and 3rd heap memory area. As the fault vanishes with larger size, I have a feeling that you might inadvertently create a heap overflow when initializing/using the mem areas later, and maybe Windows' heap protection doesn't let you request new heap memory if it would lead to a heap overflow (reporting the error at creation, not usage, wouldn't be helpful, but I don't code under Windows and know nothing about how this is handled).

Comment: It means better to look for mistakes in other parts of the program.

Comment: You say this code crashes; put it in a `main()` and add the includes needed to make a small compilable version of the bit that crashes. Then we can rule out if this code crashes or not.

Comment: if you can't get a valgrind-like program, I hope you don't have too many other variables... You could #define calloc to allocate one more cell to all allocations, paint the last cell with a pattern (eg 0xCC), and with your debugger, where reaching the problematic area, inspect that each variable still has its 0xCC trailing. Bonne chance.

Comment: here you go for the whole function @gnometorule (see edit in the question).
(it's a BicGSTAB algorithm with matrice A written in row index sparse format, for the curious...)

Comment: @koan tried with a main, works pretty well but with different small sizes (n<10), haven't tried with bigger n but it wouldn't change anything... would it ? (I can't check every size until the n=120000 I need anyway ^^)

Comment: @olivm yeah I'm screwed if I don't use a valgrind-like program then... i'll try it (I guess I can't escape that !). merci en tout cas !

Comment: Assuming you're using `glibc`, try running the program with an environment variable `MALLOC_CHECK_=2` (note the trailing underscore). This might be an easy way to zero in on the problem before trying the big guns of valgrind.

Comment: Alright thanks I think I've got some good ideas to begin with, that might take some time considering I don't know half the techniques I saw here, but that's why I'm here for !
I'll tell you if I find the solution. And if I don't find it too. And if I have other questions about that...

Comment: From my incomplete understanding of your code, it appears that the two functions called by atimes() might try to write into position (n+1) of the heap-allocated variables (local variable in functions called: b[]). if yes, that would be heap corruption. It depends on ija[] whose values are not mentioned, except that it could (should)be n+2 in 1, which you use as ija[k] -1. this doesn't quite fit what you describe, but it's the only possible heap corruption I saw (albeit first allocated var corrupting 2nd, not 3rd 4th - I think -, if any).

Comment: I finally found the problem in my program : I had to check line by line to eventually find an incorrect size of array. So the error was really earlier, I didn't know memory allocations could cause problems so late in the program...
I couldn't get a memory debugger that works on Windows with code::blocks, that could be helpful so if someone know one that would be great ! (I know it's not the topic, sorry...)
See you and thanks again